Problem connecting to the server on node js + Nginx + SSL Cloudflare
I have the following problem.
When I try to make a request from web flutter to a node js server I get the following error.
(https://i.sstatic.net/YVudEBx7.png)
When I go to https://techproguide.store I get this
(https://i.sstatic.net/pBhrPGkf.png)
I created a certificate on cloudflare and added it.
I make a request from the client  to the server like this
(https://i.sstatic.net/02EMVTCY.png)
Here is my server code
(https://i.sstatic.net/JflMEfD2.png)
const express = require('express')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const cors = require('cors')
const https = require('https')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    },
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

const app = express()
const server = https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'key.pem')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'cert.pem')),
    },
    app
)
const io = socketIo(server)

const port = 8443


Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
